# Freeing up struct created with malloc who's member also had a malloc

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

Let's say I have a `struct` for implementing vectors in C like this:

```
struct cvector {
    unsigned int size;     // indicates number of element in the vector
    unsigned int capacity; // indicates length of the array
    int* data;             // array to store the actual data
};
typedef struct cvector* cvector;
```

Then I create this vector like this:

```
cvector cvector_create() {
    cvector retval = (cvector)malloc(sizeof(struct cvector));
    retval->capacity = 8;
    retval->size = 0;
    retval->data = (int*)malloc(retval->capacity * sizeof(int));

    return retval;
}
```

I use `malloc` for both allocating memory for the struct and for allocating memory for the internal `int` array.

For freeing up my `cvector` I use this:

```
void cvector_free(cvector vector) {
    free(vector);
}
```

My question is, do I need to free the internal `int` array as well separately like this: `free(vector->data)` or is freeing up only the `struct` is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to `free` also `vector->data`, the rule is: one call to `free` per each call to `malloc`

if you are under C99, you can use flexible array members:

```
struct cvector {
    unsigned int size;     // indicates number of element in the vector
    unsigned int capacity; // indicates length of the array
    int data[];            // array to store the actual data
};
```

Notice that `int data[];` must be the last member of the `struct`.

Then, you reserve space in this way:

```
cvector cvector_create() {
    cvector retval = malloc(sizeof(struct cvector) + (sizeof(int) * 8));
    retval->capacity = 8;
    retval->size = 0;
    return retval;
}
```

Now, calling `free(vector)` is enough since `vector` and `vector->data` are on the same block.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. That `malloc(sizeof(struct cvector) + (sizeof(int) * 8));` part confuses me a bit though. How does the compiler know what struct members to allocate memory for? For example what happens when I have a struct with multiple int arrays and I want to use the method you introduced above?

Comment: Because the flexible member must always be the last member and the extra space (8 ints) is used for it.

Comment: So if I have a `struct mystruct` with `... ; int data1[]; int data2[]; int data3[];` members, I can do a `malloc(sizeof(mystruct) + (sizeof(int)*10) + (sizeof(int)*10) + (sizeof(int)*10))` as long as those three member are the last one in the order of my struct members?

Comment: @szenadam, nops :) a `struct` can only have one flexible array member.